# "Branching Factor" in military and industrial organizations?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

In math, [branching factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_factor) measures the (average) number of descendants in a tree; e.g., the branching factor of a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) is 2.

How is the same number called when applied to the [**military**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_organization) (usually *three*: 3 companies in a battalion, 3 battalions in a regiment, 3 regiments in a brigade/division &c) and **industry** (e.g., at least/at most/on average *seven* direct reports for each manager).

E.g., the book [How Google Works](http://www.howgoogleworks.net/) recommends branching factor of *at least* seven, except that it does not use that expression.

Comment: I've heard it (or some other feature) called the _Divisional Wedge_ in some contexts, but I think that has more to do with the number of combatants versus the number of non-combatants than with the canonical sizes of particular units.

Comment: @JohnLawler: are you talking about [Tooth-to-tail ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooth-to-tail_ratio)? (that's definitely _not_ what I am asking about)

Comment: Very possibly. I don't know enough to say, though the metaphor looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is called ***degree*** or ***degree of branching***. (as organizations, including military, are hierarchical.)

> Degree of branching refers to the number of direct subordinates or children an object has (in graph theory, equivalent to the number of other vertices connected to via outgoing arcs, in a directed graph a node has). Hierarchies can be categorized based on the "maximum degree", the highest degree present in the system as a whole. Categorization in this way yields two broad classes: *linear* and *branching*.
>
> [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy#Terminology)

Comment: [googling for "degree of branching"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22degree+of+branching%22) only returns results for [polymer architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_architecture#Effect_of_architecture_on_physical_properties), so, apparently, it is not all that common when applied to hierarchies. But, I guess, I will have to settle for it. Thanks!

Comment: @sds: I realized that also but didn't mention. Maybe, simply _degree_ is more common.